# how can i Create a Area of a triangle using haskell

Tags: haskell

Hello i just wanna ask how to create area of a rectangle in Haskell. This is my code

```
main = do
putStrLn"Enter base"
base <- getLine
putStrLn"Enter height"
height <- getLine
putStrLn("The area is: " ++ (height * base) /2)
```

Error is in a statement:

```
putStrLn("The area is : " ++(height *base) /2)
```

Comment: What have you got for a rectangle? What code have you got so far? If you're stuck starting with haskell, try http://learnyouahaskell.com/

Comment: wait gonna post my code @AndrewC

Comment: Thanks - that's much better now - we can see how you're thinking. If you're getting an error message, could you pop that in too? You've got an attempted solution now.

Comment: It appears your main issue, asside from knowing how to format SO questions, is knowledge of the `read` function for parsing strings obtained from `getLine` into integers used in the computation.  `putStrLn ("The area is: " ++ ((read height * read base) / 2))`

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Your Right how can i correct that Error?

Comment: @AndrewC I hope that it will be reopened again

Comment: Yup - could you include the text of your error message?

Comment: @AndrewC it Reopened :)

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson can you answer now my question? please

Comment: @AndrewC can you answer my question?

Comment: @user2714693 There's no need to ask individuals to answer - someone will always come along and answer soon enough. You did well to stick around and respond to questions.

Comment: @user2714693 I did answer that question, see the code at the end of my first comment.

Answer (score 9):

Firstly, you should indent after a `do`, and use spaces between functions and their arguments.

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Enter base"
    base <- getLine
    putStrLn "Enter height"
    height <- getLine
    putStrLn ("The area is: " ++  show ((read height * read base) /2))
```

The main issue is that in Haskell, data is not automatically converted between types, so you can't do numerical arithmetic on Strings and have to be explicit about what you want.

(This type of compile-time checking removes a great many sources of bugs - it's better to spot problems early, even if it seems picky at first.)

We need to `read` the String to make a number, and then `show` the result to turn it back into a String, so that's why we need `show ((read height * read base) /2)`

By the way, this seems to be calculating the area of a triangle rather than a rectangle!

### Improving - pure code

Your code would be better if you made the main functionality - triangle calculation - separate from the IO, so writing

```
triangle base height = height * base / 2

main = do
    putStrLn "Enter base"
    base <- readLn      -- readLn is handy
    putStrLn "Enter height"
    height <- readLn
    putStr "The area is: "
    print (triangle base height)  -- print is also handy
```

`readLn` does a `getLine` then uses `read` on the result.
`print` does `show` and then `putStrLn`.
I used `putStr` which doesn't start a newline to use fewer brackets!

Comment: Very nice. Just one more tip for @user2714693: it's good practice to always include the type above functions other than `main`. It helps the compiler as well as you when you're reading it later.

Comment: @rogaos Indeed - very good practice. I was just skipping the _Introduction to the Num Typeclass_ bit.

Comment: You could also do `print $ triangle base height` to save on parentheses.

Comment: How did I not know about `readLn`? I've been importing `Control.Applicative` and doing `read <$> getLine` all this time. Thanks for a handy function!

Comment: @kqr But `pureFunction <$> getLine` is not only great style, you can use it with other functions, but even better, you can use `<*>` to use functions with more than one argument, so if you skip the prompts, you could write`main = triangle <$> readLn <*> readLn >>= print`. Control.Applicative is full of great style and idiomatic functional programming.

Comment: @AndrewC Absolutely. I love writing stuff in an applicative style – it just feels so smooth and simple. It's just that `readLn` in this particular case seems a lot easier!